# Disable Google's "Did you mean"

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to disable Google's "Did you mean: ..."?

**Background:**
When I search for something *similar* to a known word, I often can not find many relevant results.

**Example:** There is an [article](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoind) for `bitcoind` but google does not show me, see image below. Even the other Google-results on the webpage shown on the screenshot do not include the desired reference-link.

[image]

There are probably more interesting results I can not find due to this issue. So is there any way to disable this "feature" of the Google search?

Comment: A workaround: Use quotation marks for the relevant search term, like so: `"bitcoind" reference`

Comment: Have you tried to google for a solution? Because it hasn't changed for the last 15 years at least.

Comment: To note, when it says this "Did you mean" it doesn't mean that it's showing the results for "bitcoin reference" instead of "bitcoind reference" (actually one result after the one in your screenshot is the "People also ask panel with the "What is Bitcoind daemon?" link to the same link you write about.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for a literal term using the quotation marks. This means the term *has* to be searched.

In your case you can put any of these in the search bar:

- "bitcoind" reference
- "bitcoind reference"